# Assuming inducing norm for given metric on a linear space

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces, isometry

Let's start with a concrete example. Can I assume that for a metric $d(x,y) = \sqrt{|x-y|}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, there is only one possible norm to be assumed to induce this metric, say $\sqrt{|x|_2}= \sum_k x_k^2$? I know that this is not a norm, but how can I possibly know, there is no other possible candidate?

More generally, what can be assumed about the inducing norm for a given metric? I'm guessing it might even boil down to isometry.

Comment: If two norms induce the same metric they are equivalent.

Comment: I'm seeing now, it has to checked, if $d(x,0)$ satisfies all characteristics of a norm. By assumption of a linear space, the term is well-defined. I don't see where equivalence of norms comes into play here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By definition** a norm $\|.\|$ is induced by a metric $d$ if $\|x-y\|=d(x,y)$. Putting $y=0$ we get $d(x,0)=\|x\|$. So there cannot be any other norm than $d(x,0)$ which induces $d$.

If your question is : under what conditions on a metric $d$ does there exist a norm inducing it then the answer is simple:

a) $d(cx,0)=|c|d(x,0)$

b) $d(x+y,0) \leq d(x.0)+d(y,0)$

These two conditions are necessary and suffcient.